# When clause in pyspark gives an error "name 'when' is not defined"

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

With the below code I am getting an error message, name 'when' is not defined.

```
voter_df = voter_df.withColumn('random_val',
when(voter_df.TITLE == 'Councilmember', F.rand())
.when(voter_df.TITLE == 'Mayor', 2)
.otherwise(0))
```

Add a column to voter_df named random_val with the results of the F.rand() method for any voter with the title Councilmember. Set random_val to 2 for the Mayor. Set any other title to the value 0

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Error: Add a column to voter_df named random_val with the results of the F.rand() method for any voter with the title Councilmember. Set random_val to 2 for the Mayor. Set any other title to the value 0

Comment: What is that? We’re still missing the [mcve], by the way.

Comment: Might be unrelated but could help someone, `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second when statement is a method of dataframe, but the first when statement is not.

Solution:
use `....'random_val',F.when(....`

Answer (score 0):

use
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32712210)